# How to assign Shortcut for "Go to the next location in the list" in "Find Results 1" window?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How to assign Shortcut for  "Go to the next location in the list" in "Find Results 1" window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SWEAR it used to be what you listed, but it doesn't work anymore.  If you do a global search and want to go to each found result one after another, it now looks like the shortcut is **Edit.GoToNextLocation**

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a shortcut to the **Edit.GoToFindResults1NextLocation** command in Visual Studio keyboard options.

Comment: This is for the editor, I want it for "Find Results" Window.